# Gmaps4Rails: Plot markes/pointers randomly within a given range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

Given latitude and longitude of a location say `27.1231 and 72.3454` how do I **randomly plot points within a circle of radius say `10km`** with the above `lat and log as the center`?

It's somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8138054/1552570) (?)

**EDIT**

**It's a geocoder question and not a Gmaps4rails one**

How to get the co-ordinates of random points within a given range?

Answer (score 0):

you may use [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#spherical) with  random `distance` and  `heading`

Comment: how do I use that ? I'm totally new to this.

Comment: `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset.computeOffset(LatLng, randomNumberBetween1and10000, randomNumberBetween0and360)`